# ms sql Не правильно выводятся данные по запросу дате и времени

Tags: sql-server

При запросе

`SELECT *
FROM Report_data
WHERE [Дата и время] >= '2020.02.02 00:00' AND [Дата и время] <= '2020.02.03 00:00' 
ORDER BY [Дата и время]`

выдает мне данные с 2020.02.02 00:58 по *2020.02.04 07:49* - это последняя реальная запись в базе

`SELECT *
FROM Report_data
WHERE [Дата и время] >= '2020.02.03 00:00' AND [Дата и время] <= '2020.02.04 00:00' 
ORDER BY [Дата и время]`

не выдает данных

Comment: Вопрос решил убрав разделители

Comment: Используйте формат ISO 8601 во избежание разночтений: `WHERE [Дата и время] >= '2020-02-02T00:00:00' AND [Дата и время] <= '2020-02-03T00:00:00'`